# How to change font in Firefox Reader View?

Tags: firefox

Firefox Reader View has two fonts, `serif` and `sans-serif`. I want to change these fonts. How can I do that?

[image]

Comment: For modern version of Firefox look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52033767/how-to-edit-css-styling-of-firefox-reader-view

Answer (score 6):

*2019 answer:*

If the Firefox Reader View can no longer be customized,
you could use the alternative add-on
[Readability based Reader View](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/readability-based-reader-view/),
in order to "declutter webpages for better reading experience".

More information is to be found in its
[home page](https://add0n.com/chrome-reader-view.html),
from which I quote this text:

> **Q:** Can I change the background color on the "Reader View" mode?
>
> **A:** Yes, on the left side of the page, you will see a button with "Aa" label. Press this button once to open the UI control panel. **You
> can change the font-family, font-size, line-height and the color of
> the page** right from this panel. It is also possible to further
> customize each of the three provided modes by inserting your own
> user-defined custom styles. Use the options page to insert the CSS
> code.

In the settings for the extension, find "Custom styling (reader view)", custom CSS rules can be added here to override what font(s) are used when selecting serif/sans-serif in the GUI. Example:

```css
body[data-font=serif] {
  font-family: 'My Serif Font', serif !important;
}

body[data-font=sans-serif] {
  font-family: 'My Sans-Serif Font', sans-serif !important;
}
```

You can also create rules that only apply for different background color settings, as per [the documentation](https://webextension.org/listing/chrome-reader-view.html#faq5):

```css
body[data-mode=sepia] {
  color: green !important;
}
body[data-mode=light] {
  color: blue !important;
}
body[data-mode=dark] {
  color: red !important;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I wanted to change the background colour to pure black and the font colour to pure white for the "Dark" theme of the Reader. The answer that uses `userContent.css` from 2016 seems to be outdated, and did not work on FireFox 89. After searching the web and countless testing, here is the solution I have found.

1. Enable userstyles from `about:config` by setting `toolkit.legacyUserProfileCustomizations.stylesheets` to **true**
2. Find your profile folder in `about:support`, look in the table for **Profile folder** and click the <kbd>Open Folder</kbd> button.
3. In your profile folder's root create the subfolder `/chrome` and a file named `userContent.css`.
   <sub>Example on Windows: `C:\Users\`[your Windows ID]`\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\`[random ID]`\chrome\userContent.css`</sub>
4. The CSS for changing the colours of the Dark theme was:

```css
    @-moz-document url-prefix("about:reader")
    {
        body.dark
        {
                color: #FFFFFF !important;
                background-color: #000000 !important;
        }
    }
```

5. Restart FireFox to apply the style.

Here is some [reference for customizing the fonts with CSS](https://devdocs.io/css/css_fonts).

Comment: Worked for me on Firefox 94.0.2, but since you need to set `toolkit.legacyUserProfileCustomizations.stylesheets = true` it will probably be removed in future

Comment: this seems to be broken yet again. userChrome styles work but the document-matching selector apparently not anymore

Comment: sorry, nevermind, it does work. I confused `userChrome.css` and `userContent.css`.

Answer (score 3):

There's a detailed description to do this by adding a **userContent.css** in your user profile at [How to Customize Firefox Reader View for Better Readability](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/customize-reader-view-theme-firefox/) (Hongkiat blog). Also see this Reddit thread, [I want to edit chrome://global/skin/aboutReader.css How do I do it?](https://www.reddit.com/r/firefox/comments/3iq9iu/i_want_to_edit_chromeglobalskinaboutreadercss_how/)

`...\Profiles\<your-profile-folder>\chrome\userContent.css`

There is also [How can I add the CSS styles used by Firefox reader mode?](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1069513) on the Mozilla support forum which says to modify `#moz-reader-content` in:

```
chrome://global/skin/aboutReaderControls.css
chrome://global/skin/aboutReaderContent.css
```

...but is silent on how to do that.

Comment: Please note that userChrome.css and userContent.css are disabled by default in firefox version 69 and newer.

If this guide doesn't work for you, make sure that userContent is enabeld by going to about:config and search for toolkit.legacyUserProfileCustomizations.stylesheets and set it to true then restart your browser.
https://www.ghacks.net/2019/05/24/firefox-69-userchrome-css-and-usercontent-css-disabled-by-default/

Answer (score 3):

Here's a way to do it based on [matt wilkie's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1146113/112593), for Linux systems (it should be similar for Windows and MacOS*):

```
$ cd ~/.mozilla/firefox/*.default
$ mkdir -p chrome && cd chrome
$ echo 'body.serif { font-family: "URW Palladio L" !important; }' >> userContent.css
```

(I used the "URW Palladio L" font for demonstration, as it's the closest font commonly available on Linux systems to Book Antiqua / Palatino, which are my go-to choices for serif text.)

The `!important` is required because the `userContent.css` stylesheet is loaded before the reader ones.

<sub>* To find the profile folder, navigate to `about:support` (or use the menu Help > Troubleshooting Information) and click the "Open Directory" button next to the "Profile Directory" entry.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

If a page is available in Reader View,  Reader mode will appear in the address bar. Options will appear to the left when you view a page in Reader View, and you have the **Aa** icon, click on it, and there you can change the font.

+

Install Reader 40.0 addon if you can't edit the font. With that addon, you can change it too.

Comment: thank you , but I know reader view what to do, I don't know how to change font reader view... I don't want install new add-on, I want change fonts of reader view.

Comment: Sorry mate, but I don't think it's possible without addon.

Comment: ok, I agree with you, but I don't want install add-on for this job

Comment: Just try it, maybe it'll work out for you. You can uninstall it afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

I wondered why I didn't face this problem.

Turns out it's because I enforce my font preferences on *all* websites by unchecking the box in font preferences that says "Allow pages to choose their own fonts, instead of your selections above". Turns out this enforces this rule in the reader mode as well (which is good for accessibility).

This is not exactly what the original question is for, but I thought I'll leave this in case it's useful.

[image: Allow pages to choose their own fonts, instead of your selections above]

Answer (score -1):

These fonts are tied to your firefox font preferences. You can change them by going to `Preferences > Content > Advanced` and choosing your fonts for serif and sans-serif styles.

Screenshot of the Preferences view:
[image: Screenshot of the Preferences view]

Screenshot of the changed Firefox reader font:

[image: Screenshot of the changed Firefox reader font]

As you can see in the images above, I have changed the serif font to Seravek.

Comment: At least in Firefox 47 those settings do not affect Reader View in any way. They only affect what the browser selects as the font when the CSS font-family evaluates to those four values.

Comment: @ElmoAllén the preference settings will affect Reader View if *"Allow pages to choose their own fonts..."* is not checked. (Which still may not desirable since it affects all pages, not just reader view. It does provide an option which might work for some though.)

Answer (score -1):

2022 (in Firefox 100):

1. In the URL bar, enter: `about:config` . Click on Accept Risks and continue button
2. In the search field, type `reader`
   This lists out all the parameters that can be configured including font type, content width, background color etc.

Once you choose the font type, you can edit the font by:

1. In the browser url bar, type `about:preferences`
2. scroll down the page until you see the `Fonts` section. Click on `advanced` and choose the required font.

Reference: https://www.trishtech.com/2022/04/how-to-change-fonts-in-mozilla-firefox-reader-mode/

Comment: typing in `reader` does NOT show configurable colors etc., only fixed scheme string values. And changing `reader.font_type` (which can also be done from the reader interface) does also NOT reveal any hidden settings that weren't there in the normal preferences dialog either. And the `fonts` section in the preferences does NOT allow changing the reader font.