# Change the font of Reader, Firefox 57

Tags: fonts, firefox-quantum

This look like a duplicate of [How to change font of Reader View firefox?](https://superuser.com/questions/975920/how-to-change-font-of-reader-view-firefox) but none of the answers there work since Firefox Quantum

All points to `userContent.css` but none worked.

1. use `@-moz-document` from [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/firefox/comments/3iq9iu/i_want_to_edit_chromeglobalskinaboutreadercss_how/)

```
    @-moz-document url-prefix("about:reader") {
      #container {
        font-family: "courier new" !important;
        color: blue !important;

    }
```

Result: text didn't turn blue and font didn't change.

2. using `:root` selector from [a blog](https://www.hongkiat.com/blog/customize-reader-view-theme-firefox/)

```
:root[hasbrowserhandlers="true"] body.dark.serif,
:root[hasbrowserhandlers="true"] body.dark.serif #reader-domain {
        font-family: "courier new" !important;
        color: blue !important;
}
```

Result: text didn't turn blue and font didn't change.

This is assembled by myself:

```
body.serif .moz-reader-content {
        font-family: "Helvetica" !important;
        color: red !important;
}
```

It achieved the change of text color, but the font remained. The inspector shows my rule `"Helvetica" !important;` takes precedence over the default rule, but the 'calculated' CSS rule at work is `font-family: serif, "Helvetica";` with `serif` inserted before `Helvetica` with the all mighty hand of God.

If you achieved changing the font of Reader mode (without changing what defines `serif` by user preference please answer below.

Comment: If there is a question already, but it's outdated, you can place a bounty to attract new answers, rather than posting a new question.

Comment: Since I have enough reputation to spare, I placed a bounty on the question for you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change font in Firefox Reader View?](https://superuser.com/questions/975920/how-to-change-font-in-firefox-reader-view)